# resx file string bad encoding

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass a string contained in a `.resx` file which have:

```
|        Key       |        Content       |
|__________________|______________________|
|PasswordMismatch  | La password è diversa|
```

for doing so I have create a section inside a `.cshtml` file:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<UserController> Localizer

@section script {
   var Lang = {
        PasswordMismatch '@Localizer["PasswordMismatch"]
   };
}
```

as you can see I've injected the localization of `UserController` then I created a javascript object which contains `PasswordMismatch`. 
The main problem is that if I write in the console: `console.log(Lang);` I'll get this result:

```
La password &#xE8; diversa
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting the output of `console.log(Lang)` to be?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin well the correct string `La password è diversa`

Comment: What is the actual string that you are receiving?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin oh sorry stackoverflow editor messed all up, anyway, is this: `La password &#xE8; diversa`